# Overriding methods from JavaScript function-based classes in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to override a object method defined in JavaScript (ES5) function-based class:

```
var JSClass = function() {
  this.start = function() {
    console.log('JSClass.start()');
  }
}
```

Then calling `start()` method prints as expected:

```
let o1 = new JSClass();
o1.start();
// prints: JSClass.start()
```

However, if I try to extend this object with a TypeScript class such as:

```
class TSClass extends JSClass {
  start() {
    super.start();
    console.log('TSClass.start()');
  }

  otherStart() {
    this.start();
    console.log('TSClass.otherStart()');
  }
}
```

... then `TSClass::start()` is never called. Only the `start()` defined in `JSClass`.

```
let o2 = new TSClass();
o2.start();
o2.otherStart();
```

This prints just:

```
JSClass.start()
JSClass.start()
TSClass.otherStart()
```

I'd expect to print:

```
// by calling: o2.start();
JSClass.start()
TSClass.start()
// by calling: o2.otherStart();
JSClass.start()
TSClass.start()
TSClass.otherStart()
```

Is this by design? Then how can I extend ES5 object methods with TypeScript?

See live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/martinsikora/2sunkmq7/

Edit: I ended up using this.

```
class TSClass extends JSClass {

  constructor() {
    var oldStart = this.start;
    this.start = () => {
      oldStart.call(this);
      console.log('TSClass.start()');
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding the `start` method to `JSClass` as a class member instead of class method.
In order to make it a method you need to add it to the prototype:

```
var JSClass = function () {}

JSClass.prototype.start = function () {
    console.log('JSClass.start()');
}
```

Then this:

```
let o2 = new TSClass();
o2.start();
o2.otherStart();
```

Results in:

```
JSClass.start()
TSClass.start()
JSClass.start()
TSClass.start()
TSClass.otherStart()
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't think about this. Unfortunately, I'm extending a third party library which uses only property methods but at the end I did just like in my edit.