# Angular 2 rxjs nested Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I wish to create a function that returns an `Observable<any>` but before returning another asyncronous task must complete (an `Observable<string>`), in order for a value to be passed to the returned `Observable`.

```
 @Injectable()
 export class MyComponent
 {

      GetAuthToken = function() : Observable<string>
      {
           return this._storageService.GetAsString('authToken');
      }

      GetData = function(authToken) : Observable<any>
      {

           let headers = new Headers();
           headers.append('authToken', authToken);
           var getUsers = this._http.get('/api/endpoint', { headers: headers })
                 .map((resonse: Response) => resonse.json()));

           return getUsers;        
      }


      DoIt = function() : Observable<any>
      {
          this.GetAuthToken ().Subsribe(t=> {
              return GetData(t); 
          })
      }          


 }
```

So instead of passing the authToken parameter into the GetData function, I wish to execute the GetAuthToken function within the GetData function, wait for its completion, and then still return the http observable.

Executing the DoIt function would return the subscriber, not the GetData Observable

Comment: Completely unrelated question: Why are you using syntax: `GetAuthToken = function() {...}` and not `GetAuthToken() {...}` like everyone else (I know these two method definitions aren't the same though)?

Comment: Use `Observable.forkJoin`, check this: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md

Comment: @Martin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn

Comment: @camaron the first observable needs to finish executing before the second begins. And I need to return the Observable<Response> from the Http service, not an amalgamation

Comment: @gunwin I understand the difference but I really doubt you need to use it. This btw makes extending your class very complicated. It's basically the same problem as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398381/overriding-methods-from-javascript-function-based-classes-in-typescript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [`concatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html?#instance-method-concatMap):

```
DoIt() : Observable<any>
{
    return this.GetAuthToken()
        .concatMap(token => this.GetData(token)); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect. This works. My WebAPI service wasn't running, which caused my null problem. Thank you!

Comment: similar problem  - concatMap() works perfect !  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible using [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)

```
DoIt() : Observable<any>
{
    return this.GetAuthToken()
        .flatMap(token => this.GetData(token)); 
}
```